# How to make function that outputs multiple minima of a function which takes arrays as input?

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, scipy-optimize, scipy-optimize-minimize

```py
a1 = [array] #shape = (m,)
a2 = [array] #shape = (n,)
a  = func(a1,a2) # func returns an array of shape = (n, m)
# a is an array of shape = (n, m)
a_sol = [] # empty list
for i in a1:
    f = lambda x: float(func(np.array(i), np.array(x)))
    res = scipy.optimize.minimize_scalar(f)
    a_sol.append(res)
```

Is there a way to do this without for loop? Instead of passing each element of `a1` one at a time, is there a way to find the minima for all the values of a1 at once, without using the for loop?

Comment: Your function returns an ARRAY. How do expect minimize_scalar to work?

Comment: There, I made the required edit, now `f` will return a float as long as `x` and `i` are scalars.

Answer (score 0):

```
from functools import partial

func1 = partial(func, array1)
scipy.optimize.minimize(func1)
```

I don't understand what you mean about your function returning an array. What does it mean to minimize an array?

Comment: Sorry my bad, your doubt made me rethink my entire question, now I've re framed it please take a look.